# API usage: How to change the 'participant_note' field in the Participant entry for an event

Tags: api

I need to update the 'participant_note' field for a few Event Participants via the API. I can't figure out how to do this using the API explorer (it seems the explorer does not recognize 'participant_note' as a valid field).
Here is an example of a Participant get call

> {
>               "contact_id": "11111",
>               "contact_type": "Individual",
>               "contact_sub_type": "",
>               "sort_name": "Last, First",
>               "display_name": "First Last",
>               "event_id": "1",
>               "event_title": "Readable Name",
>               "event_start_date": "2014-01-01 00:00:00",
>               "event_end_date": "2014-01-01 00:00:00",
>               "participant_id": "1",
>               "participant_fee_level": "",
>               "participant_fee_amount": "",
>               "participant_fee_currency": "",
>               "event_type": "Some Type",
>               "participant_status_id": "1",
>               "participant_status": "Registered",
>               "participant_role_id": "1",
>               "participant_role": "Attendee",
>               "participant_register_date": "2014-01-01 00:00:00",
>               "participant_source": "",
>               "participant_note": "",
>               "participant_is_pay_later": "0",
>               "participant_is_test": "0",
>               "participant_registered_by_id": "",
>               "participant_discount_name": "",
>               "participant_campaign_id": "",
>               "id": "1"
>           }

Answer (score 2):

i figured it out:

> entity=Participant
>   action=create
>   json={
>        "sequential":1,
>        "id":"", THIS IS PARTICIPANT ID
>        "participant_note":""
>        }

Answer (score 0):

Look for it in civicrm_note (Entry *Note* in the API Explorer) It will be tied back to the Participant Table via civicrm_note.entity_table and civicrm_note.entity_id.

Comment: i tried fiddling with the Note get in API explorer, but with no parameters selected i don't see anything except for entities with 'note' returned 'participant_note' doesn't appear tied to this.
also i dont see 'entity_id' or 'entity_table' values for my events. where do i find these?